# Drupal 7 Admin Slow On Azure Setup

Tags: php, azure, drupal, drupal-7

I have recently moved a Drupal 7 site over to Azure on a Windows app service running PHP. I am also using Azure's MySQL database instance.

Since moving over to Azure, I noticed that the site is laggy when you are logged into the Drupal dashboard. Pages can take around 6-8 seconds to load when just clicking around the various dashboard areas. The site when not logged into Drupal works absolutely fine, so somewhere along the line there is something in Drupal Admin causing the slow down.

The app service is on a P1V2 tier, which is more than what the Drupal application requires and judging by the usage stats, it's not exceeding any resources.

Is there anything I am missing specifically to cause this slow down? I have removed any unneeded plugins and disabled the update module.

Comment: It's normal that admin pages are displayed slower since public pages are displayed from cache and admin (that is pages for authenticated users) are generated real time. But you have to provide more info so people can help you. Without that...check on drupal 7 system requirements and see if all of them are met.

Comment: @MilanG The Drupal 7 requirements is the first thing I looked at and meets the server requirements and followed the Azure Drupal hosting best practices. Unfortunately, the Drupal site got handed over and not something I built.

Comment: And did you check Drupal's error log? Anything interested there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, I found the workaround was to downgrade the PHP framework version from 7.2 to 7.1 even though the version of Drupal I was using is compatible with 7.2. After making this change from within the Azure configuration screen, the dashboard load time reduced considerably.